# Using Eval in aspx only if property exists in item - throws DataBinding exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an aspx page that has a repeater with 5 fields.
Those fields are filled with two different item types.
One item has 3 properties : "A" "B" "C" and the other has "A" "B" "C" "D" "E".

I want to use the same repeater for both but show only the relevant properties for each of them.
When trying to use Eval on a propery "D" with item 1 i get the error:
DataBinding: 'Item1' does not contain a property with the name 'D'.

I tried to use if statement but it did not help and when trying to use "ItemDataBound" event it also throws exception when trying to load Item1 (not throwing when trying to load Item2 with all the properties.

How can i Eval only if property exists?

Answer (score 8):

To solve your issue it is important to understand how `Eval` works under the hood.

The `Eval` statement is converted to call to [`DataBinder.Eval`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/DataBinder.cs,65) method on aspx compilation stage. This means that expression `<%# Eval("A") %>` is a shortened version of `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "A") #>`. If you will follow the execution path of `Eval` method you'll see that exception is thrown in [`GetPropertyValue`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/DataBinder.cs,160) if container object does not contain a property:

```
// get a PropertyDescriptor using case-insensitive lookup
PropertyDescriptor pd = GetPropertiesFromCache(container).Find(propName, true);
if (pd != null) {
    prop = pd.GetValue(container);
}
else {
    throw new HttpException(SR.GetString(SR.DataBinder_Prop_Not_Found, container.GetType().FullName, propName));
}
```

To suppress the exception thrown by `Eval` you can write your own `SafeEval` method and put it in your base page class:

```
public abstract class BasePage: Page
{
    public object SafeEval(object container, string expression)
    {
        try
        {
            return DataBinder.Eval(container, expression);
        }
        catch (HttpException e)
        {
            // Write error details to minimize the harm caused by suppressed exception 
            Trace.Write("DataBinding", "Failed to process the Eval expression", e);
        }

        return "Put here whatever default value you want";
    }
}
```

Then use it inside repeater:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# SafeEval(Container.DataItem, "A")  %>'></asp:Label>
```

While this will solve your issue this will expose another issue such as absence of error notifications when binding expression is really wrong/mistyped. So I would suggest to have two different repeaters for each item type instead of trying to find the workaround for the standard ASP.NET `Eval` behavior.

Comment: I chose to use a Dto object that will represent both types and bind the dto list to the repeater.
This way i still have the DataBinder.Eval error handling ability and it is enough for me needs.

But , since your answer is also very good and you invested time on it, i will mark it as an answer.

Comment: @FelProNet I think it would be better if you'll show how you fixed that issue for yourself and then accept it as answer. It will possibly help others with the same issue.

Comment: why catch only HttpException? The DataBinder.Eval metadata says it can throw ArgumentNullException too, maybe just catch every exception to avoid cases where the user thinks they're safe from any exception.

Comment: also not sure if the Trace context can be null, in that case can use Trace?.Write in recent C# versions

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis, `DataBinder.Eval` throws `ArgumentException` when `container` argument is null or the property name is null or empty string. This is not responsibility of `SafeEval` method to deal with argument validation, it should deal only with data binding exceptions which are `HttpException`. [Reference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/DataBinder.cs,160). [Trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace) in my code snippet is a static class, it is not property or field.

Comment: Btw, I thought it also throws such if it can't find the property